# jQuery syntax for using with variables

Tags: jquery, variables

jQuery not working with variable. the issue is with this line:

```
$('img[alt = id]').trigger("click");
```

if I change it to

```
$('img[alt = "6"]').trigger("click");
```

Everything works as expected. I just can't workout how to use a variable instead of a value within the quotes. I have tried putting id in single / double quotes with no luck. I'm sure it will be something obvious. Can anyone help.

This is the full code.

```
$(window).load(function () {
        // run code
       // $('img[alt ="6"]').trigger("click");
        var id = localStorage.getItem("CustomerID");
        $('img[alt = id]').trigger("click");
      //  window.alert(id);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine a string and use that instead:

```
$('img[alt = "' + 6 + '"]').trigger("click");
```

Here it is as a variable:

```
var id = 6;
$('img[alt = "' + id + '"]').trigger("click");
```

It's called [string concatenation](http://2ality.com/2011/10/string-concatenation.html).

Comment: Thanks mate. So simple when you know how. I will accept your answer once I can in few minutes.

Comment: I actually tried something similar. $('img[alt = ' + id + ']').trigger("click"); But I user it without the double quotes, I didn't realise they are needed as part of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Watch this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Example:

```
$(`img[alt = "${id}"]`).trigger("click");
```